# Publish a Database Project as part of TestInitialize

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

Is there a way to publish a database project (within the same solution) as part of a `TestInitialize` method when running unit (or integration in this case) tests in Visual Studio?

The idea is that each integration test which actually hits a database should be hitting a known good and clean database, and the best way to do that is to completely refresh the database with each test.  I've been looking around online and finding a lot of related information about databases and testing, but nothing about refreshing the database when running automated tests.  Nor am I finding anything in the Visual Studio interface, or at least I'm missing it.

I'm using Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 RC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following [a helpful link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8376809/328193) from a colleague, I ended up using `Process.Start` to run `sqlpackage.exe` for the deployments.  It's not as clean from a Visual Studio perspective as I'd hoped, but it gets the job done.  My bootstrapping now looks like this:

```
private const string SQL_PUBLISH_COMMAND = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DAC\bin\sqlpackage.exe";
private const string SQL_PUBLISH_COMMAND_ARGUMENTS = @"/Action:Publish /SourceFile:C:\Data\Code\NewEdCo\Domain\NewEdCo.Database.SQLExpress\bin\Debug\NewEdCo.Database.SQLExpress.dacpac /Properties:CreateNewDatabase=True /TargetServerName:hactar\sqlexpress2012 /TargetDatabaseName:NewEdCoTest";


private void DeployTestDatabase()
{
    var procInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        Arguments = SQL_PUBLISH_COMMAND_ARGUMENTS,
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        ErrorDialog = false,
        FileName = SQL_PUBLISH_COMMAND,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        UseShellExecute = false
    };
    var proc = new Process
    {
        StartInfo = procInfo
    };

    proc.Start();
    var result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
}

[TestInitialize]
public void BootstrapTests()
{
    DeployTestDatabase();
}

[TestCleanup]
public void TearDownTests()
{
    DeployTestDatabase();
}
```

The options used for the `ProcessStartInfo` and the reading of the standard output (even though I don't do anything with it yet) are there to keep the task synchronous.  That way the tests aren't stepping on each other.  This increases execution time for integration tests, but that's fine for my needs.

I realize I'm doing a complete refresh both before *and* after.  If that turns out to take far too long as my number of tests increases, I'll re-think it.  But for now I like to make sure it's refreshed before the test as well as leaving no trace after the test.

[MSDN has an extensive list of options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh550080.aspx) for `sqlpackage.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

Facing the same problem I've found the [DACSmash](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DacSmash/) NuGet package was easy to get working from the example on the [project site](https://github.com/merbla/DacSmash).

Answer (score 0):

> The idea is that each integration test which actually hits a database should be hitting a known good and clean database, and the best way to do that is to completely refresh the database with each test.

I faced similar problem recently and decided to follow the same db recreation route initially, but test runs got to be too slow, when there are a lot of them.

So I tried a few other things in addition and as alternative to make tests faster while still resilient:

- Splitting tests to Read and Write in regard to the mutations they introduce to avoid db restore for the former;
- Using transient transaction, which was reverted after the test run;
- Using database snapshots intead of full database backup restore/recreation;
- Using a pool of databases, which allowed to parallelize tests;
- Running sql server in docker with use of dotnet-testcontainers;

Ended up with a [Reseed](https://github.com/v-zubritsky/Reseed) library which uses simple Insert/Delete scripts, but does it efficiently. Hope it might be of some help for anyone who encounters the same issue.

[Respawn](https://github.com/jbogard/Respawn) is also sth to consider for db cleanup.