# Azure continuous deployment from GitHub and database upgrades

Tags: database, git, azure, continuous-deployment

I have a Web application that I usually deployed using Web Deploy directly from Visual Studio (whatever branch I am currently using in VS - normally *master*). But now I'm introducing a second web app on Azure that will be built from the **same repo but different branch**. To make things simpler I will be configuring both Web apps on Azure to integrate directly with GitHub and associate them with specific branch.

I also added two additional `web.config` files: `Web.Primary.config` and `Web.Secondary.config` and configured app settings on Azure portal of each web app by adding additional value `SCM_BUILD_ARGS` and set them to

```
SCM_BUILD_ARGS=-p:PublishProfile=Primary // in primary web app
SCM_BUILD_ARGS=-p:PublishProfile=Secondary // in secondary web app
```

which I understand **will transform correct config file** with specific external services' configurations (DB connection, mail server, etc.).

Now the additional step that I would like to include in continuous deployment is run a set of SQL scripts that I have in my repo that I used to manually upgrade database during Web Deploy in VS. Individual scripts are actually doing specific database upgrade steps:

1. backup current tables - backup creates a set of Backup_OriginalTableName tables that are copied from existing ones and populated with existing data
2. drop whole DB model - all non-backup objects are being dropped from procedures, functions, types, views, tables...
3. create model - creates all tables, views and indices
4. create user types
5. create user functions
6. create stored procedures
7. restore data to new tables from backup tables - this step may occasionally break if we introduce new non-nullable columns to tables in the new model don't have defaults defined on them; I will somehow have to mitigate this problem by adding an additional script that will add missing columns to backup tables and give them some defaults, but that's a completely different issue.

I used to also have a set of batch files (BAT) in my VS solution that simply executed `sqlcmd` against specific database instance and executed these scripts in predefined order (as above). Hence I had batches:

- `Recreate Local.bat` - this one used additional SQL scripts to not restore from backup but rather to recreate an empty DB with only lookup tables being populated and some default data for development purposes (like predefined test users)
- `Restore Local.bat` - I used this script to simply restore database from backup tables discarding any invalid data I may have created while debugging/testing since last DB recreate/upgrade/restore
- `Upgrade Local.bat` - upgrade local development DB executing scripts mentioned above
- `Upgrade Production.bat` - upgrade production DB on Azure executing scripts mentioned above

So to support the whole deployment process I was now doing manually in VS I would now like to also execute these scripts against specific Azure SQL DB during continuous deployment. I suppose I should be running these right after code deployment because if that one fails, DB shouldn't be upgraded either.

I'm a bit confused where and how to do this? Can I configure this somewhere in Azure portal? I was looking for resources on the Web but I can't seem to find any relevant information how to do additional deployment steps to execute these scripts. I think this is some everyday scenario as it's hard to think of web apps not requiring databases these days.

Maybe it's just my process that is wrong for DB upgrade/deployment so let me also know if there is any other *normal* way that does DB upgrade/migration with continuous deployment on Azure... I may change my process to accommodate for this.

> ***Note 1**: I'm not using Entity Framework or any other full blown ORM. I'm rather using NPoco and all my DB logic is built in SPs that DAL is using.*
>
> ***Note 2**: I'm aware of recently introduced staging capabilities of Azure, but my apps are on cheaper plan that doesn't support staging and I want to keep it this way as I may be introducing additional web apps along the way that will be using additional code branches and resources (DB, mail etc.)*

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like your db project is a good candidate for [SSDT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/jj650015) and inclusion in source control. You can create a MyDB.sqlproj that builds your db as a dacpac, and then you can use [SqlPackage.exe Publish](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh550080(v=vs.103).aspx) to accomplish your deployment to Azure.

We recently brought our databases under source control and follow a similar process to build and automatically deploy them (but not to a SQL Azure DB). We've found the source control, SSDT tooling support, and automated deployment options to be worth the effort of setting up and maintaining our project this way.

This SO question has some good notes for Azure deployment of a dacpac using SSDT:

[How to publish DACPAC file to a SQL Server database project via SQLPackage.exe of SSDT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20513530/how-to-publish-dacpac-file-to-a-sql-server-database-project-via-sqlpackage-exe-o)