# SSDT projects + integration/end-to-end tests + TearDown

Tags: c#, nunit, integration-testing, xunit, sql-server-data-tools

Let us say I have a sql server data tools project (SSDT) and a bunch of integration/end-to-end tests (deliberate not saying unit tests). Is there a way to TearDown and republish the existing test database via code from the test class library?

PS:

I am currently trying this (paths and file names simplified):

```
var p = new System.Diagnostics.Process
{
    StartInfo =
    {
    FileName =
        @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DAC\bin\sqlpackage.exe /Action:Publish /SourceFile:“D:\Database_20151114_18-23-29.dacpac” Profile:”D:\LocalDatabase.publish.xml”",
    UseShellExecute = true
    }
};
p.Start();
```

Unfortunately, I am getting:

```
{"The system cannot find the file specified"}
```

The dacpac and xml file is definitely there. Any ideas? Also, is it possible to create the latest dacpac file automatically?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming SSDT is installed on the machine running the tests, you can run **sqlpackage.exe** via a shell command in TearDown. sqlpackage.exe is what SSDT uses to publish a database.

```
[TearDown]
public void TearDown() {
   System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
   p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DAC\bin\sqlpackage.exe /Action:Publish /SourceFile:C:\DbProject\bin\Debug\DbProject.dacpac /TargetServerName:localhost /TargetDatabaseName:TestDb";
   p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
   p.Start();
}
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8376809/65775) for the sqlpackage.exe arguments. Note that sqlpackage.exe may be in a different path than the one I used above.

Comment: I have SSDT installed locally but just cannot find sqlpackage.exe. Any ideas?

Comment: Ignore me, just found it. In my case: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DAC\bin

Answer (score 1):

Something like this seems to do the trick:

```
const string dacPacFileName = @"D:\Bla.dacpac";
var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BlaConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

var dacPackage = DacPackage.Load(dacPacFileName);
var dacServices = new DacServices(connectionString);      
var dacOptions = new DacDeployOptions();
dacOptions.CreateNewDatabase = true;
dacServices.Deploy(dacPackage, "Bla", true, dacOptions);
```

However, it still does require the manual creation of a dapac file. Can this be automated as well?

Comment: How to enable SSDT diagnostics when using DacServices object? DacDeployOptions does not seem to include that

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's absolutely possible to automate the whole process.  It roughly goes like this:

- Add a reference to the `Microsoft.Build` library to your end-to-end tests project
- Build your test project from code using that library to get an up to date DacPac
- Add a reference to the `Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac` library using [either NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.DacFx/) or by [installing the SSDT tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017)
- Use the Dac related classes and methods in that library to publish a fresh copy of the database at the start of each test using the DacPac the build created.

This [excellent existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34002580/how-do-i-publish-a-ssdt-database-from-code) has all the details on how to do that.