# How do I publish a SSDT Database from code

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-data-tools

We have `SQLServer01.Publish.xml` when I double click this file and publish, it publishes a database to sqlServer01.

I wanted to ask can we publish this profile from code somehow ?

Comment: call `msbuild` like this http://blog.danskingdom.com/using-msbuild-to-publish-a-vs-2012-ssdt-sqlproj-database-project-the-same-way-as-a-vs-2010-dbproj-database-project/

Answer (score 9):

SSDT seems to like DacPac for this kind of thing. There is a `DacServices` utility class in `Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac`. I think this will require SSDT to be installed on the machine you plan on running this code.

```
public class DacPacUtility
{
    public void DeployDacPac( string connString, string dacpacPath, string targetDbName )
    {
        var dbServices = new DacServices( connString );

        var dbPackage = DacPackage.Load( new FileStream( dacpacPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read ), DacSchemaModelStorageType.Memory, FileAccess.Read );

        var dbDeployOptions = new DacDeployOptions()
        {
            SqlCommandVariableValues =
            {
                new KeyValuePair< string, string >( "debug", "false" )
            },
            CreateNewDatabase = true,
            BlockOnPossibleDataLoss = false,
            BlockWhenDriftDetected = false
        };

        dbServices.Deploy( dbPackage, targetDbName, upgradeExisting : true, options : dbDeployOptions );
    }
}
```

**Bonus**: you can use the  `Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project` namespace to new up a `Project` object and build it locally for integration testing using the resulting built dacpac to initialize a test.

```
[SetUpFixture]
public class TestSetup
{
    [SetUp]
    public void SetUpTests()
    {
        var projectPath = @"C:SomeDirectory";
        var project = new Project( projectPath );
        project.Build();
        ProjectCollection.GlobalProjectCollection.UnloadProject( project );

        var dacPac = new DacPacUtility();
        var connString = "Data Source=(localdb)\ProjectsV12;Initial Catalog=Tests;Integrated Security=True";
        var dacPacPath = projectPath + "..\bin\projectName.dacpac";
        dacPac.DeployDacPac(connString, dacPacPath, "Tests");
     }
     [TearDown]
     public void TearDownTests()
     {
       // TODO: delete db or run other cleanup scripts
     }
 }
```

**References**:

[Deborah's Developer MindScape: Deploying A DACPAC](http://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/deploying-a-dacpac/)

[Latest SSDT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx)

[SSDT for VS 2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/archive/2012/09/14/new-ssdt-power-tools-now-for-both-visual-studio-2010-and-visual-studio-2012.aspx)

**Where to get `Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac` and so `DacService`**

There are a couple of ways to get the `Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac` library, either:

- Add [the Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.DacFx.x64/)
- Or [install the SSDT tools on your dev machine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017), and then [reference the DLL](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/be484b63-a6cc-4dac-a2c2-78a56ff5b502/where-is-the-microsoftsqlserverdacdll-that-includes-support-for-sql-server-2014?forum=ssdt).

Comment: thanks for you reply, but I cant find DACServices, is it because we are using 2008R2 and vs2010 ?

Comment: Warning: While most of this is great, I recommend not using `new FileStream` to load the dacpac; If you have a dependancy on another dacpac, for example `master.dacpac`, and that the SDK is not deployed on the machine running that code, it won't be able to find it in the same directory (what the engine tries to do) since there is no directory, only a stream, from the point of view of the engine. Instead, just pass the path of the file, and let the engine handle it.

Comment: Thanks @Tipx! Your tip saved me a lot of trouble. For the reference finding to work you also need "IncludeCompositeObjects = true" in the DacDeployOptions. @Ashtonian could you please update the answer  as per these comments?